# What is the color of my guitar?

Tags: vocabulary

I have been asked about the color of my guitar. It's the color of wood, I think is called "natural". Which would be the best way to mention the color of my guitar?

Comment: natural wood (color)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, "natural" is a common way of describing wood finishes, particularly when it comes to guitars.  For example, here's a guitar described by the maker as a "[Douglas Spad Pro **Natural**](http://www.rondomusic.com/spadpronat.html)":

[image]

Here's a can of wood stain called "Natural":

[image]

Answer (score 2):

I believe it will be best to find out the specific color swatch from the makers of the guitar. However, the most common color swatch for wooden color types are Amber, Natural, Cherry Sunburst, Violin Burst, Aged Natural, Antique Burst, Walnut and Ebony Transparent.

Since your guitar is a wooden color type, you can look up the above mentioned color swatches for that of your guitar.

Answer (score 1):

I think that the name of the color would also depend on the wood the body of your guitar was made of. As far as I was able to find it out, the most common wood for this may be maple, or rosewood, or ash, or mahogany.

[Here's the link](http://www.hoovedesigns.com/woods.html) to the types of wood and their colors. On checking out the color of your guitar there, you may say if its color is *natural maple* or whatever natural particular wood you find there.

Answer (score 0):

I would go for a more general description, rather than try for a single color name that fits. "It's a light colored wood" or "it's a dark red wood". If you just said a color name, that might imply that it's painted that solid color.

Although if you know the actual type of wood, you could mention that, especially if talking to someone who is familiar with guitars and may therefore be familiar with the different wood types, e.g., rosewood is a very dark reddish brown while mahogany is sort of a medium-brown and alder and maple are very light colored woods.